# How to avoid grouping separator in NSNumberFormater until 5 digits

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, numbers, nsnumberformatter

I have an application that needs to display metric units in millimeters and based on the research that I have done (e.g. http://physics.nist.gov/cuu/pdf/sp811.pdf), it is recommended that you don't add grouping separators until you have 5 digits. Is this possible with NSNumberFormatter? I know I could test the value and enable/disable grouping based on its size but I would rather use the appropriate configuration for the NSNumberFormatter if it exists.  (BTW, I am on Mac OS X)  So for example:

3456 should be shown as 3456 mm

10234 should be shown as 10,234 mm (assuming comma is the grouping separator)

I have read the Apple docs and didn't see anything.  I experimented with different searches to find the answer on Stackoverflow but couldn't find a similar question.

Here is how I am currently setting up my NSNumberFormatter:

```
if (numberFormatter == nil) {
    numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [numberFormatter setRoundingMode:NSNumberFormatterRoundHalfUp];
    [numberFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
    [numberFormatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
    [numberFormatter setMinimumFractionDigits:0];
    [numberFormatter setMaximumFractionDigits:2];
}

NSNumber *numberInMM = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:fLenInMMs];
NSString *numberStr = [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:numberInMM];
numberStr = [numberStr stringByAppendingString:@" mm"];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
long long d = fLenInMMs;
if (d>9999) {
    NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter=nil;
    if (numberFormatter == nil) {
        numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
        [numberFormatter setRoundingMode:NSNumberFormatterRoundHalfUp];
        [numberFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
        [numberFormatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
        [numberFormatter setMinimumFractionDigits:0];
        [numberFormatter setMaximumFractionDigits:2];
    }

    NSNumber *numberInMM = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:fLenInMMs];
    NSString *numberStr = [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:numberInMM];
    numberStr = [numberStr stringByAppendingString:@" mm"];
    NSLog(@"%@", numberStr);
}
else {
    NSNumber *numberInMM = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:fLenInMMs];
NSString *numberStr =   [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ mm",numberInMM];
}
```

**EDIT**

You can also subclass `NSNumberFormatter`  and implement

```
- (NSString *)stringFromNumber:(NSNumber *)number
{
    NSNumber *nm = [NSNumber numberWithInt:9999];

    if (NSOrderedAscending==[number compare:nm]) {
        return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ mm",number];
    }

    return [super stringFromNumber:number];
}
```

Comment: Actually, if you read my question I said I would prefer not to do this and instead configure the NSNumberFormatter to do it for me.  Also, the else part of your solution would not have the correct decimal formatting.  Are you saying that it is not possible to do this with NSNumberFormatter?